# rospack depends error

Tags: ros, beginner-tutorials, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have just installed ros goovy wihout errors. Now I follow the beginner tutorial and at tutorial "CreatingPackage" with catkin I have this error:

> rospack depens1 beginner_tutorial

> [rospack] Error: no such package beginner_tutorials

Any suggestion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60926/rospack-depends-error./) by [Ziko](https://answers.ros.org/users/4701/ziko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2013-04-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure without more information but possible duplicate of [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/41652/ros-beginner-tutorials-problem/).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just had the exact same problem you did, following the tutorial, and I solved it by following one of the suggestions in the referenced duplicate problem:
"source devel/setup.bash".

---

Originally posted by [cyberguy42](https://answers.ros.org/users/5314/cyberguy42/) with karma: 188 on 2013-07-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2